# Gauge transformation of vector superfields

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills

I am working my way through Srednicki and am at Chapter 95 which introduces supersymmetry.

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$
In Chapter 95, Srednicki introduces the idea of a vector superfield, which he says is not subject to any constraints save for the fact that it's Hermitian.

Later when Srednicki comes to doing gauge transformations on this vector superfield, he does so by introducing a left-handed chiral superfield $\Xi$ term to the vector superfield

$$V\rightarrow V+i(\Xi^\dag + \Xi)$$

to accomplish the gauge transformation.

Srednicki says that the $i(\Xi^\dag + \Xi)$ term is a vector superfield.

My question is this:  is there any reason why this $i(\Xi^\dag + \Xi)$ term must be a vector superfield beyond the fact that it is hermitian and has terms which we could put in correspondence with the terms in V?

I.e. is there something special about combining $\Xi$ terms in this way?

Comment: Sec. 4.5 on page 12 of these notes https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/lect4.pdf answers your question fairly well.

Comment: Sorry for being so long in replying.  Thank you for the reference.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the reference helpful, you can upvote my previous comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A superfield is the most general function one can define on a superspace.  However, in general, when Taylor expanded in superspace coordinates they typically contain many "component fields" i.e. the coefficients of the expansion which are valued in real space. Thus these completely general fields do not form irreducible field representations of the super-Poincare algebra.  In order to talk about supersymmetry in a field formalism we must then find appropriate constraints on these generic superfields such that the component functions line up with the representation theory of the super-Poincare algebra.  These come in many forms, the chiral superfields are *defined* to vanish when acted on by one of the super-covariant derivatives, while the vector superfield is *defined* to be a superfield satisfying the hermiticity condition.  So, no, there is no reason that gauge transformation term forms a vector superfield other than the fact that it is Hermitian as that is the definition of what a vector superfield is.

Comment: Thank you.  I had kind of figured, but wanted to be sure.